# Is the underscore in target="_blank" no longer needed?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, anchor

Today I made a typo while helping someone with a question and wrote `target="blank"` instead of `target="_blank"`. The interesting thing was that it still worked. I decided to try it out in other browsers as well to see if it was only Chrome that allowed for `target="blank"` without the underscore, but it seems to work in Firefox and Safari as well.

Is there a reason why the underscore can be dropped? And if it's legitimate to write it as `target="blank"`, why do most if not all sources still say to write it out as `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have `target="blank"`, open it twice and it opens in the same window. If you have `target="_blank"` twice, it opens in two different windows. You can check using:

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="blank">Google</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" target="blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

Same with, `_blank` opening in two different windows:

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a>
```

In simple terms, it would be considered as `blank` will be the name of the new window, while `_blank` is a **special keyword**, opens a new window without a name. Correct me if I am wrong.